# Powershell can't even open notepad

Tags: windows, powershell

Actually, **my** Powershell can't resolve many commands **while cmd/bash can**: node, git, npm, etc...

```
PS C:\Users\vssen> notepad
notepad : The term 'notepad' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ notepad
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (notepad:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But PowerShell **MUST** at least open notepad with "notepad" command!

**Note: it is opening notepad by "notepad.exe" command, but it must do it without ".exe".**

I think this error also make issues to me while I am working with git and node too, and I see a lot of opened issues similar to that, and there is still no answer.
Example error behavior with other commands:
npm: open new console;
npm.exe --version: no output;
git: not found;
node: not found;
git.exe: open and close console;
node.exe: open nodejs console window;

**THINGS I TRIED**:

- clear all user and system paths, adding only for nodejs for example, or only system32
- DISM
- sfc /scannow
- **Installation of separated PowerShell 7 (cross platform) - SAME ISSUE!**
- Get-Command can't find path without ".exe", can with ".exe"

```
PS C:\Users\vssen> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.906
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.906
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**env variables**

vssen:
Path: `C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\vssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\vssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\vssen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\vssen\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\vssen\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;`

system:
Path: `C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Conan\conan;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\`

I've validated every path in env Path, all links are valid (and PowerShell & cmd must work with invalid links as well!)

```
C:\Users\vssen>where where
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe


C:\Users\vssen>where notepad
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

Maybe someone know Microsoft developers) Help is much appreciated! i don't want to reinstall Windows please...

PS:
all possible related and non-related things to mention

- OS Build: 19043.985
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0 (don't know what is it)
- I have WSL
- use nodejs via nvm
- have bash (from git installer)

Comment: Make a new, test Windows Profile.  Log into the new profile. Now see if Power Shell works correctly.

Comment: @John created, behavior is the same.

Comment: "actually, PowerShell can't do many things which cmd/bash can: node, git, npm, etc..." - It certainly can.  The Microsoft document even uses an example where it calls notepad (without a file extension) so this behavior is due to a system configuration.  **This is most likely an system variable environmental which explains the reason a new Windows profile would not work.**  Care you [edit] your question and provide the contents of that variable?  *If you end up reinstalling Windows I will be unable to help you.*

Comment: @Ramhound updated question with Paths!

Comment: The answer I provided did not involve reinstalling Windows.  I suggested a Repair.

Comment: @John it was not me who voted down)

Comment: @John - An in-place repair still involves reinstalling Windows (I can prove that’s the case with Microsoft documentation)

Comment: What I suggested fixes issues and loses nothing. That is why I suggested it, And yes I have done these.

Comment: @VitalySenko - Within a command prompt, what is the output of `where where`, I want to verify that works.

Comment: @Vitaly Senko, you have an environmental issue that you need to figure out. YOu can prove it is an environmental issue, simply by sp[inning up a pristine VM, and call notepad or whatever. Windows 10 has a prebuilt VM called the ***' Windows Sandbox'***  that you can use for this validation. It's not a permanent VM, when you close it, it's gone until you restart it again. You just need to enable the feature.  Read the docs about it. Now, all that being said, what is causing your issues, that is just going to be an effort on your side.

Comment: As for this... `...Powershell can't do many things while cmd/bash can: node, git, npm, etc...`, that is simply not valid, as folks do this every day, and it is fully documented/demo'd my MS, and many articles/videos that exist, all over the web. I use all of those tools daily in virtually all my engagements, all in Powershell/VSCode, etc.

Comment: What are the values in your PATHEXT system variable?

Comment: @Ramhound updated the question with ```where where``` output, it's correct.

Comment: @Anaksunaman i don't have PATHNEXT system variable (neither user var)

Comment: @postanote thanks a lot, yes, i know that powershell can do this, i describe my (and not only my) issue with powershell not able to resolve commands correctly

Comment: This issue is strange.  1) notepad.exe is located in two locations `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32` this is confirmed by running `where notepad`, 2) I had to remove both of those paths before I could reproduce this issue (after nearly 2 hours of work) which tells me it's a PowerShell environment issue, likely the profile, that effects the entire system which is the reason the new user was affected by the behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound the real magic is why POWERSHELL 7 (completely separated shell!) is affected by this!

Comment: @Ramhound i think there is some dll which is used by both powershell 5 and powershell 7 for resolving paths, and the issue is in that dll. I just don't know what it can be.

Comment: @Anaksunaman you saved me

Comment: @VitalySenko Glad to help. =)

Comment: I don't really care for the credit, but I also technically suggested and asked about the PATHEXT.  Of course I deleted that comment after I tested removing .EXE from the list and being able to still run Notepad within PowerShell.

Comment: @VitalySenko - PowerShell 7 is PowerShell and it separately is not a separate shell, PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7 can just co-exist.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell still relies on the system PATH variable and the PATHEXE variable to resolve commands that execute a program, which describes which file extensions will be executed.

Some very bad software probably removed this environmental variable from my machine, so I've added it as default:

`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

Once I restore the system variable I was able to start Notepad from PowerShell

Comment: in my case the uppercase extensions didn't work, but lowercase did